# Image not showing div class

Tags: python, html, image

When I insert an image on my html file it not showing on the page

index.html

```
<!-- start banner section -->
<section class="xs-banner-sec owl-carousel banner-slider">
    <div class="banner-slider-item banner-item1" style="background-image: url(assets/images/banner-slider/banner_slider_1.jpg);">
        <div class="slider-table">
            <div class="slider-table-cell">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                            <div class="banner-content text-center">
                                <h2>Best Gardening Service</h2>
                                <p>Wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring
                                    whole
                                    heart.
                                </p>
```

and this is my folder
[image]

Comment: maybe add a point in the start `./assets/images/banner-slider/banner_slider_1.jpg` and inside "" chars like this "assets/images/banner-slider/banner_slider_1.jpg"

Comment: tried both, not working

Comment: I will try to create a folder with your same structure and try to see what happen

Comment: <div class="banner-slider-item banner-item1" style="background-image: url(assets/images/banner-slider/banner_slider_1.jpg)">   i removed the semicolon hope it works now

Comment: @SamarthMotka doesnt work either

Comment: did you closed the div tags?

Comment: @SamarthMotka yes

Answer (score 0):

Does the div have a width or height? Divs will not take up space by default even with a background image as it isnt concidered content. Try giving it a height of 200px and a width of 200px just to test.

Comment: I think is for this, great!

Comment: added ```width="200" height="200"``` to the div class and it not working either

Comment: Add it within a style component, width and height does not aplly to all tags

Answer (score 0):

You should write background instead of background -image. cause it was not working for me until I changed it to background

```
<div class="banner-slider-item banner-item1" style="background: url(assets/images/banner-slider/banner_slider_1.jpg);">
```